# Android supported emoticons

Tags: android, unicode

I'm trying to display unicode characters (more specifically emojis) in my android application. Many of the unicode characters from http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode seem to be unsupported by the default android font system.

For example:

```
myTextView.setText("\u1F602 \u1F603 \u263A");
```

will only correctly display the last unicode character (\u263A) according to the link above. Like I said, I'm guessing this a result of unsupported unicode characters by the default font. How do I go about supporting those unicode characters with the default android representation? Do I need to choose a new font, and if so, how do I determine if that font supports what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Different Androids have different fonts. If you develop software to be used in more than on device (installation), you generally cannot know which fonts are available and what characters they cover. So for emoticons, it is certainly much safer to use images.

Comment: Use an icon font with the glyphs you need, such as [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)